# Difference of meaning between the two sentences

Tags: differences, be

Whenever I see "to be", I don't get the whole meaning, so please help me with other scenarios which could help me get rid of my fear with "to be".

1. I'm going to be hanging out tomorrow.
2. I'm going to hang out tomorrow.

Comment: 'Be [verb]ing' is the continuous tense; in this case, it indicates that you will spend some time hanging out.

Comment: In this case they're essentially equivalent, because hanging out is a continuous activity.